# How to interpret this Cambridge, Blackheath here?

Tags: meaning

I’d like to ask about the following sentence from The Missing Three Quarter by Conan Doyle.

> I didn’t think there was a soul in England who didn’t know Godfrey
>   Staunton, the crack three-quarter, Cambridge, Blackheath, and five
>   Internationals.

This Godfrey Staunton is at the moment belongs to the rugby team at Cambridge University. So what the word Blackheath refers to here? I don’t think the relation between these words, Cambridge and Blackheath, is like “Los Angels, California”. If it’s not “Cambridge in (/ of) Blackheath”, I’m guessing Blackheath is the name of high school Godfrey went to.  So this part means as “Godfrey Staunton was an excellent three-quarter back at Blackheath high school and he is now an excellent three-quarter back at Cambridge University.” Am I right? 
Can someone tell me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Blackheath is a district in London. (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackheath,_London)

This is just a narration that says that Godfrey was popular at Cambridge University, moreover, in his district, Blackheath, and actually was a star of five Internationals.

Comment: If you scroll down to the 'Sport' section from Mariia's link, you will find [another link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackheath_F.C.) about Blackheath Rugby Club.

Comment: @KateBunting ‘s comment indicates this answer really misses the point. Nothing to do with popularity, just fame because of athletic ability at rugby football. Cambridge University, Blackheath and his country (presumably England) were the rugby teams he represented. Feel free to correct your answer, or I can add one of my own.